# Get data for specific time range

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to select records between 7 pm to 7 am from 2018-09-24 until 2018-09-26 for each day.
example:

> 2018-09-24_____7 pm to 7 am____ 2018-09-25
>   2018-09-25_____7 pm to 7 am____ 2018-09-26
>   2018-09-26_____7 pm to 7am____ 2018-09-27

by using this code A: I get records from 7pm(2018-09-24) until 7am(2018-09-26).

```
If Trim(cbShift.Text) = "Morning" Then
startdt = (S_date.Text) & " 19:00:00.317"
enddt = (E_date.Text) & " 07:00:00.160" End If
SELECT FROM tb_test
WHERE  (DateCreate   BETWEEN convert(datetime,@startdt) AND convert(datetime,@enddt))
```

and by using this code B:

```
WHERE  DateCreate > convert(datetime,'2018-09-24') AND DateCreate <=
DATEADD(day,1,convert(datetime,'2018-09-26'))
AND (DATEPART(hh,DateCreate) >= 19 and DATEPART(hh,DateCreate) <= 24  )

or DateCreate > convert(datetime,'2018-09-24') AND DateCreate <=
DATEADD(day,1,convert(datetime,'2018-09-26'))
AND (DATEPART(hh,DateCreate) >= 0 and DATEPART(hh,DateCreate) <= 6  )
```

I get

> 2018-09-24 (00->7 and 19 ->24) , 2018-09-25 (00->7 and 19 ->24), and 2018-09-26 (00->7 and 19 ->24)

Is there a way I can do to get a data exactly like my example above. 
Thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks for your help. its work well after i applied those code , and i did  change it a lil bit. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think that the problem is with the order of evaluation in your `WHERE` clause. I *always* use brackets around `OR` operators in SQL.  The following works on MySQL 5.6.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tb_test
WHERE  datecreate between '2018-09-24 19:00:00' and '2018-09-26 07:00:00'
AND (hour(DateCreate) >= 19 or hour(DateCreate) < 7);
```

For reference, I used this test schema:

```
CREATE table tb_test
(datecreate datetime);

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW generator_16
AS SELECT 0 n UNION ALL SELECT 1  UNION ALL SELECT 2  UNION ALL 
 SELECT 3   UNION ALL SELECT 4  UNION ALL SELECT 5  UNION ALL
 SELECT 6   UNION ALL SELECT 7  UNION ALL SELECT 8  UNION ALL
 SELECT 9   UNION ALL SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 11 UNION ALL
 SELECT 12  UNION ALL SELECT 13 UNION ALL SELECT 14 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 15;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW generator_256
AS SELECT ( ( hi.n << 4 ) | lo.n ) AS n
 FROM generator_16 lo, generator_16 hi;

INSERT INTO tb_test
SELECT date_add("2018-09-24",interval n hour)
FROM generator_256;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to look at the problem is to say that you want `DateCreate` -12 hours to be between 7am and 7pm on the days of interest. So, try this (note we don't add times to `startdt` and `enddt`):

```
If Trim(cbShift.Text) = "Morning" Then
startdt = (S_date.Text)
enddt = (E_date.Text) End If
SELECT FROM tb_test
WHERE DateCreate - INTERVAL 12 HOUR BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME,@startdt) AND CONVERT(DATETIME,@enddt) AND
      TIME(DateCreate - INTERVAL 12 HOUR) BETWEEN '07:00:00' AND '19:00:00'
```

Comment: Nice use of `TIME()` - I updated my answer to include a version that uses that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Let's create some test data:

```
mysql> create table t (id int auto_increment, stamp datetime, primary key (id));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.46 sec)

mysql> insert into t (stamp) values
    ->   ('2018-09-24 18:59:59'), ('2018-09-24 19:00:00'), ('2018-09-24 19:00:01'),
    ->   ('2018-09-25 06:59:59'), ('2018-09-25 07:00:00'), ('2018-09-25 07:00:01'),
    ->   ('2018-09-25 18:59:59'), ('2018-09-25 19:00:00'), ('2018-09-25 19:00:01'),
    ->   ('2018-09-26 06:59:59'), ('2018-09-26 07:00:00'), ('2018-09-26 07:00:01'),
    ->   ('2018-09-26 18:59:59'), ('2018-09-26 19:00:00'), ('2018-09-26 19:00:01'),
    ->   ('2018-09-27 06:59:59'), ('2018-09-27 07:00:00'), ('2018-09-27 07:00:01');
Query OK, 18 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 18  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from t;
+----+---------------------+
| id | stamp               |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | 2018-09-24 18:59:59 |
|  2 | 2018-09-24 19:00:00 |
|  3 | 2018-09-24 19:00:01 |
|  4 | 2018-09-25 06:59:59 |
|  5 | 2018-09-25 07:00:00 |
|  6 | 2018-09-25 07:00:01 |
|  7 | 2018-09-25 18:59:59 |
|  8 | 2018-09-25 19:00:00 |
|  9 | 2018-09-25 19:00:01 |
| 10 | 2018-09-26 06:59:59 |
| 11 | 2018-09-26 07:00:00 |
| 12 | 2018-09-26 07:00:01 |
| 13 | 2018-09-26 18:59:59 |
| 14 | 2018-09-26 19:00:00 |
| 15 | 2018-09-26 19:00:01 |
| 16 | 2018-09-27 06:59:59 |
| 17 | 2018-09-27 07:00:00 |
| 18 | 2018-09-27 07:00:01 |
+----+---------------------+
18 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now, we want to select out from `2018-09-24 19:00:00` to `2018-09-25 07:00:00`:

```
mysql> select * from t where stamp between (@start := '2018-09-24 19:00:00') and date_add(@start, interval 12 hour);
+----+---------------------+
| id | stamp               |
+----+---------------------+
|  2 | 2018-09-24 19:00:00 |
|  3 | 2018-09-24 19:00:01 |
|  4 | 2018-09-25 06:59:59 |
|  5 | 2018-09-25 07:00:00 |
+----+---------------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

If we want to include 3 days worth of data during those windows, we can do this using `UNION ALL`:

```
mysql> select * from t where stamp between (@start := '2018-09-24 19:00:00') and date_add(@start, interval 12 hour)
    -> union all select * from t where stamp between (@start := '2018-09-25 19:00:00') and date_add(@start, interval 12 hour)
    -> union all select * from t where stamp between (@start := '2018-09-26 19:00:00') and date_add(@start, interval 12 hour);
+----+---------------------+
| id | stamp               |
+----+---------------------+
|  2 | 2018-09-24 19:00:00 |
|  3 | 2018-09-24 19:00:01 |
|  4 | 2018-09-25 06:59:59 |
|  5 | 2018-09-25 07:00:00 |
|  8 | 2018-09-25 19:00:00 |
|  9 | 2018-09-25 19:00:01 |
| 10 | 2018-09-26 06:59:59 |
| 11 | 2018-09-26 07:00:00 |
| 14 | 2018-09-26 19:00:00 |
| 15 | 2018-09-26 19:00:01 |
| 16 | 2018-09-27 06:59:59 |
| 17 | 2018-09-27 07:00:00 |
+----+---------------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And that's how it's done.

Edited to add: After seeing Nick's answer that uses `TIME()`, that's actually a cleaner solution:

```
mysql> select * from t where date(stamp) between '2018-09-24' and '2018-09-27'
    -> and time(stamp + interval 12 hour) between '07:00:00' and '19:00:00';
+----+---------------------+
| id | stamp               |
+----+---------------------+
|  2 | 2018-09-24 19:00:00 |
|  3 | 2018-09-24 19:00:01 |
|  4 | 2018-09-25 06:59:59 |
|  5 | 2018-09-25 07:00:00 |
|  8 | 2018-09-25 19:00:00 |
|  9 | 2018-09-25 19:00:01 |
| 10 | 2018-09-26 06:59:59 |
| 11 | 2018-09-26 07:00:00 |
| 14 | 2018-09-26 19:00:00 |
| 15 | 2018-09-26 19:00:01 |
| 16 | 2018-09-27 06:59:59 |
| 17 | 2018-09-27 07:00:00 |
+----+---------------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```