# Past Midnight Query For Multiple Days In A Row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

So here is my issue.

Under first shift the query runs fine and dandy. But for second shift I have to run in two parts because the time goes past midnight.

**I would like to run the second shift in one query as I have to paste in a spreadsheet all data but twice for second shift then sort.** I have tried multiple solutions but either no results or errors.

Note that I do week at a time by request and not every week starts on same day, or may be just a few days, or in one case an entire month. All three will work as needed for the date range I put in but would be nice if I could somehow run in one query for the second shift. The second shift time would be 5 PM to 4 AM or 1700 to 0400 military time.

Thanks in advance!

```
   SELECT TOP (100000) 
   [line_ID]
  ,[VIN]
  ,[sequence]
  ,[load_time]

----------------First Shift-------------------------------

 FROM [NYSUS_SEQUENCE_MES].[dbo].[broadcasts_in]
 WHERE line_ID = 100 and  load_time > '10/08/2018' AND load_time <= D 
 ATEADD(day,1,'10/14/2018') 
 AND DATEPART(hour,load_time) >= 5 AND DATEPART(hour,load_time) <= 16
 order by load_time


-------------Second Shift----------------------------------

-------------NEED TO RUN THE TIME PARTS INDEPENDANTLY------
SELECT TOP (100000) 
   [line_ID]
  ,[VIN]
  ,[sequence]
  ,[load_time]


FROM [NYSUS_SEQUENCE_MES].[dbo].[broadcasts_in]
WHERE line_ID = 100 and  load_time > '10/08/2018' AND load_time <= 
DATEADD(day,1,'10/14/2018') 
AND DATEPART(hour,load_time) >= 17 AND DATEPART(hour,load_time) <= 2359
order by load_time


SELECT TOP (100000) 
   [line_ID]
  ,[VIN]
  ,[sequence]
  ,[load_time]

FROM [NYSUS_SEQUENCE_MES].[dbo].[broadcasts_in]
WHERE line_ID = 100 and  load_time > '10/08/2018' AND load_time <= 
DATEADD(day,1,'10/14/2018') 
AND DATEPART(hh,load_time) >= 0 AND DATEPART(hh,load_time) <= 4
order by load_time
```

Comment: Answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52601301/get-data-for-specific-time-range/52601448#52601448) might prove helpful.

Comment: Sample data and expected results would go a long way toward a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). [Start Here](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for tips to edit your question as needed.

Comment: how does `datepart(hour` return anything greater than 23? sure as heck cannot reach 2359

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your queries return the correct result, the *easy-cheesy* approach was `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM
(
        SELECT TOP (100000)
           'Query 1' AS Querymarker
          ,[line_ID]
          ,[VIN]
          ,[sequence]
          ,[load_time]

        FROM [NYSUS_SEQUENCE_MES].[dbo].[broadcasts_in]
        WHERE line_ID = 100 and  load_time > '10/08/2018' AND load_time <= 
        DATEADD(day,1,'10/14/2018') 
        AND DATEPART(hour,load_time) >= 17 AND DATEPART(hour,load_time) <= 2359

        UNION ALL    

        SELECT TOP (100000) 
           'Query 2' AS Querymarker
          ,[line_ID]
          ,[VIN]
          ,[sequence]
          ,[load_time]

        FROM [NYSUS_SEQUENCE_MES].[dbo].[broadcasts_in]
        WHERE line_ID = 100 and  load_time > '10/08/2018' AND load_time <= 
        DATEADD(day,1,'10/14/2018') 
        AND DATEPART(hh,load_time) >= 0 AND DATEPART(hh,load_time) <= 4
    ) t
    order by t.load_time;
```

#### Hint 1

I added a `Querymarker` column, which allows you to see, which query returned a row, but this is - assumably - not needed and you can remove it...

#### Hint 2

You should avoid culture dependant date formats. `10/08/2018` can be the 10th of August or the 8th of October, depending on your machine's settings. Try to use independant settings, in your case I'd tend to *unseparated* `'20181008'` (with quotes, this will be 8th of October in any case).

Comment: This worked great. I did in fact remove the Querymaker part. So simple....

Answer (score 0):

The approach below will dynamically generate a set of rows representing 2 x 12 hour shifts to cover a date range:

```
declare @start as datetime = '20180901 00:00:00'
declare @finish as datetime = '20181001 00:00:00'

;WITH digits AS (
      SELECT 0 AS n UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL
      SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9
      )
, tally AS (
      SELECT 
              d1s.n 
            + d10s.n * 10
            --+ d100s.n * 100  /* add more like this as needed */
            --+ d1000s.n * 1000  /* add more like this as needed */
            AS n
      FROM digits d1s
      CROSS JOIN digits d10s
      --CROSS JOIN digits d100s /* add more like this as needed */
      --CROSS JOIN digits d1000s /* add more like this as needed */
      )
, range as (
    select
         n
       , dateadd(hour,5,dateadd(day,n-1,@start))  shift1_start
       , dateadd(hour,17,dateadd(day,n-1,@start)) shift2_start
       , dateadd(hour,29,dateadd(day,n-1,@start)) next_shift1_start
    from tally
    where dateadd(day,n-1,@start) <= @finish
    )
select t.*
from range
inner join [NYSUS_SEQUENCE_MES].[dbo].[broadcasts_in] AS t 
    ON t.load_time >= range.shift2_start and t.load_time < next_shift1_start
order by t.load_time
```

see this demonstrated here: https://rextester.com/ODUNU15588

nb: If you need more rows just follow the same pattern of cross joins and calculation as shown. Also, if you already have a numbers table, or calendar table, that could be used instead. The generated shift boundaries look like this (dd.mm.yyyy):

```
       n       shift1_start          shift2_start        next_shift1_start      
 ---- ---- --------------------- --------------------- --------------------- 
   1    0   31.08.2018 05:00:00   31.08.2018 17:00:00   01.09.2018 05:00:00  
   2    1   01.09.2018 05:00:00   01.09.2018 17:00:00   02.09.2018 05:00:00  
...
  31   30   30.09.2018 05:00:00   30.09.2018 17:00:00   01.10.2018 05:00:00  
  32   31   01.10.2018 05:00:00   01.10.2018 17:00:00   02.10.2018 05:00:00
```

Using this approach to your problem allows you to select the data for a single shift in a single query, or distinguish between data by both shifts in a single query.

Comment: Appreciate the answer but not the results I was looking for. First response works just like I needed it too and it was so simple.

Comment: I have amended the answer. This approach - whist it appears more complex does give you greater flexibility. I also added a simpler alternative that does not require union.

Answer (score 0):

All you require is an `OR` within the `where clause` to include both allowed sets of hours:

```
select
*
from [NYSUS_SEQUENCE_MES].[dbo].[broadcasts_in]
WHERE load_time > '10/08/2018' 
AND load_time <=  DATEADD(day,1,'10/14/2018') 
AND ((DATEPART(hour,load_time) >= 0 AND DATEPART(hh,load_time) <= 4)
   OR
     (DATEPART(hour,load_time) >= 17 AND DATEPART(hour,load_time) <= 23)
     )
order by load_time
;
```

also see: https://rextester.com/SUM30585

Comment: Yes. That works too. I do not do a whole lot of intricate DB querying but I think I was over thinking it.